# less than 80% of your list has mapped to your chosen identifier type

Tags: rna-seq, go-enrichment

I am trying to do GO analysis. However, when I run DAVID, I am getting this error:

> You are either not sure which identifier type your list contains, or less than 80% of your list has mapped to your chosen identifier type. Please use the Gene Conversion Tool to determine the identifier type.
> In addition, when I am trying to add a column with gene names next to esemble ids in R in the file with differential expression genes, many genes say NA under gene name column.

I have used STAR and Salmon for the alignment,and DESEQ2 for differential expression analysis.
I have used premade indexes for both tools.
Thank you in advance!

Some of the ENSEMBL codes I used:

> ENSG00000249200 ENSG00000239920 ENSG00000242295 ENSG00000235763 ENSG00000226933 ENSG00000283632 ENSG00000235838 ENSG00000232429 ENSG00000281076 ENSG00000271042 ENSG00000229119 ENSG00000253384 ENSG00000285645 ENSG00000240627 ENSG00000213590 ENSG00000270739 ENSG00000240201 ENSG00000203531 ENSG00000271626 ENSG00000250316 ENSG00000218713 ENSG00000231548 ENSG00000231049 ENSG00000286185 ENSG00000214535 ENSG00000212961 ENSG00000219747 ENSG00000259100 ENSG00000231767 ENSG00000243175 ENSG00000236804 ENSG00000240634 ENSG00000270773 ENSG00000230267

Comment: Give some examples of identifiers that didn't map. Please note that many genes will lack GO annotations, though 80% feels a bit high there.

Comment: ENSG00000249200ENSG00000239920
ENSG00000242295
ENSG00000235763
ENSG00000226933
ENSG00000283632
ENSG00000235838
ENSG00000232429
ENSG00000281076
ENSG00000271042
ENSG00000229119
ENSG00000253384
ENSG00000285645
ENSG00000240627 ENSG00000213590
ENSG00000270739
ENSG00000240201
ENSG00000203531
ENSG00000271626
ENSG00000250316
ENSG00000218713
ENSG00000231548
ENSG00000231049
ENSG00000286185
ENSG00000214535
ENSG00000212961
ENSG00000219747
ENSG00000259100
ENSG00000231767
ENSG00000243175
ENSG00000236804
ENSG00000240634
ENSG00000270773
ENSG00000230267

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DAVID last received an update in May 2016 (https://david.ncifcrf.gov/content.jsp?file=update.html), so any additions to the Gene Ontology database since then won't be present. I checked the examples you posted in [Biomart](http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martview/8b2b5b98dc138d40cfcb7843544f6922?VIRTUALSCHEMANAME=default&ATTRIBUTES=hsapiens_gene_ensembl.default.feature_page.ensembl_gene_id%7Chsapiens_gene_ensembl.default.feature_page.go_id&FILTERS=hsapiens_gene_ensembl.default.filters.ensembl_gene_id.%22ENSG00000249200ENSG00000239920,ENSG00000242295,ENSG00000235763,ENSG00000226933,ENSG00000283632,ENSG00000235838,ENSG00000232429,ENSG00000281076,ENSG00000271042,ENSG00000229119,ENSG00000253384,ENSG00000285645,ENSG00000240627,ENSG00000213590,ENSG00000270739,ENSG00000240201,ENSG00000203531,ENSG00000271626,ENSG00000250316,ENSG00000218713,ENSG00000231548,ENSG00000231049,ENSG00000286185,ENSG00000214535,ENSG00000212961,ENSG00000219747,ENSG00000259100,ENSG00000231767,ENSG00000243175,ENSG00000236804,ENSG00000240634,ENSG00000270773,ENSG00000230267%22&VISIBLEPANEL=resultspanel) and found that only 2 have GO annotations, so you're likely not missing an immense number of genes. Having said that, you'd be best served to use a more frequently updated tool than DAVID. Around 2015 there was an outcry because it hadn't been updated in 6 years and the database was so out of date that people were getting questionable results. Have a look at one of the many Bioconductor packages for convenient free solutions that are better maintained.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!! So, there is not a problem with my index, right? I have tried gprofiler as well, but I wanted to check more tools.

Comment: Your index is fine.

Comment: Thank you a lot!